# Javascript onbeforeunload event on mobile

Tags: javascript

I have an event in my JS code to alert before onload:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  alert("You will leave...");   
}
```

In my PC browser everything works as expected, but when I try in my phone nothing happen. The browser in my phone is Chrome in IOS.

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the browser support?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp

The onunload or onbeforeunload event is supported in IE, Firefox, and Safari, but not supported properly in Chrome or Opera.
Also remember ActiveX Script have to be allowed to this happen (atleast on IE)

Comment: Is there any alternative to support all the major browsers?

Comment: @amachado
i dont think so 
please folow this link |
https://forums.asp.net/t/1912726.aspx?chrome+onbeforeunload

Comment: The links you posted seem to show that Chrome and Opera 15 onwards do support it.